# C-shell: How to create multiple arrays from a single line of standard input?

Tags: arrays, linux, shell, sed, galois-field

I need to find a way to complete the following task using C-shell (I can't use a different shell):

There is a program that outputs polynomial factors from a larger polynomial, using Galois Field calculations.  The output is a single line, and looks something like this (don't pay attention to the actual value of the numbers; I randomly chose them and they don't mathematically work out):

```
(0 1 4 6 7 8 11 12 13) = (0 1)^3 * (0 4 5) * (0 2 4 6)^4 * (0 2 3)^2
```

The way polynomial math works, if a factor is raised to an even number, then that factor is superfluous to the value of the polynomial.  Sort of like multiplying by 1.  What I need to do is extract the polynomial factors and eliminate the superfluous factors.

Using sed, I have been able to alter the above expression into the form of

```
(0 1) ^ 3 * (0 4 5) * (0 2 4 6) ^ 4 * (0 2 3) ^ 2
```

but I am unsure of how to proceed.

I want to take the above, input it into a C-shell script, and make the following array assignments:

```
Array A = (0 1)
Array B = (0 4 5)
```

I think the best route would be to first separate the polynomial factors into separate lines, like this:

```
(0 1) ^ 3
(0 4 5)
(0 2 4 6) ^ 4 
(0 2 3) ^ 2
```

but I am uncertain as to how to do this.

Can anyone provide any useful help or hints?  Be aware that the number of polynomial factors will change, but I don't expect to ever have any more than 8.  The exponent values aren't significant; I only need to determine whether they are even or odd.  I can easily do that if they are assigned to a variable or an array.  A maximum possible size of a single factor is probably around 50 individuals numbers inside the parentheses.

Comment: Where you say "[t]he output is a single line.." in the 1st paragraph, don't you mean *input* instead?

Comment: You shuld *not* use C-shell, read [Csh considered harmful](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot). So handling this as a social issue (i.e. convincing your client, manager, teacher .... of not using csh) is not a lose of time. Perhaps even your problem is much more easy to handle in a scripting language (Python, Guile, Perl, awk....). Saying "I can't use a different shell" looks like a mistake: choose a better tool for the job!

Comment: *Why* can't you use a different shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like next:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set str="(0 1) ^ 3 * (0 4 5) * (0 2 4 6) ^ 4 * (0 2 3) ^ 2"

echo "My string: ===$str==="
set arrnum = 0
foreach line ( "`echo '$str' | grep -oP '\([^)]*\)'`" )
    @ arrnum++
    set eval_line = "set array$arrnum = $line"
    eval "$eval_line"
end

echo "created $arrnum arrays (array1 .. array$arrnum)"
foreach i (`seq $arrnum`)
    set arrname = "array$i"
    echo "The content of $arrname"
    set temp = `eval echo '$'$arrname`
    foreach item ( $temp )
        echo $item
    end
end
```

It creates array1 .. arrayN for each `(x x x x x)` group.
For your string:

```
(0 1) ^ 3 * (0 4 5) * (0 2 4 6) ^ 4 * (0 2 3) ^ 2
```

prints

```
My string: ===(0 1) ^ 3 * (0 4 5) * (0 2 4 6) ^ 4 * (0 2 3) ^ 2===
created 4 arrays (array1 .. array4)
The content of array1
0
1
The content of array2
0
4
5
The content of array3
0
2
4
6
The content of array4
0
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the polynomial in a file named abc, you could use the following command to get the output you are looking for.

```
cat abc | tr '\052' '\n'
```

If you have the same in a variable say res, then you could use following command:

```
echo $res | tr '\052' '\n'
```

Comment: Why the octal number and not a simple `tr '*' '\n'`?